# WiFi Conflict with dnsmasq (OSX)

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, dnsmasq

I recently installed [dnsmasq](http://davesouth.org/stories/how-to-set-up-dnsmasq-on-snow-leopard-for-local-wildcard-domains) so I could use wildcard lookups for *.local addresses using [these instructions](http://davesouth.org/stories/how-to-set-up-dnsmasq-on-snow-leopard-for-local-wildcard-domains).

The only difference was that mine was setup to resolved .local instead of .dev, like so:

```
address=/.local/127.0.0.1
```

It was working great when directly connected to a modem, but when connecting through, say, a public WiFi it was unable to resolve anything!

```
$ dnsmasq

dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 192.168.1.129: Permission denied
```

As an interim solution I removed dnsmasq:

```
$ sudo port uninstall dnsmasq
```

And then in my network preferences, I ran Diagnostics which detected a "problem" with my DNS settings. I clicked the button to revert those changes and the WiFi began to work again.

#### How can I re-install dnsmasq and set it up to avoid that WiFi problem?  (E.g. a DNS setting I need to have or something with dnsmasq that I need to configure.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.local` conflicts with the domain used by zero-config solutions including bonjour. Choose a different domain.

If you are getting an IP address in the range 192.168.0.0/16 the domain on that network is likley `.local`.  You may also get an address in the range 169.254,0.0/16 if you are unable to contact a DHCP server to get an address.

EDIT: `localnet` is a traditional alternative to `local` for your localnetwork.  It is referenced on the dnsmasq FAQ.

Comment: So, _that_ must be why a lot of places were saying ".dev" was better that ".local" huh?

Comment: Yes, local is not an assigned domain name, but it as been co-opted.

Comment: Ok, well I've reinstalled dnsmasq and set it to dev this time. I'll let you know if it didn't work. Thanks!