# Can I use dynamic DNS with a Static DNS Entry also on OSX?

Tags: macos, networking, dns

I run a local DNS server for development so I can wildcard host names to my virtual machine. This requires a static DNS entry. This kicks out the dynamic DNS. I have added the Google DNS entry for remote DNS 8.8.8.8 as temporary workaround. Also, I don't want to use hosts files they are not as flexible as a remote.

On some networks I have to sign in or register. This requires Dynamic IP address that assigns the necessary network DNS server.

So the question is: Can I have OSX discover the DNS server through dynamic process, but still use a static entry for my local DNS server?

Comment: See [this previous question](http://superuser.com/questions/680005/in-os-x-how-can-i-prepend-127-0-0-1-to-the-list-of-dns-servers-obtained-through).